# Visual Studio Code Explorer Settings

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to make my VS Code Explorer look more like the classical Netbeans Tree View Explorer?

[Reference image](https://platform.netbeans.org/images/tutorials/nodes-3/projects-window.png)

Comment: check for some extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try File Tree View
 by Dimitar Dimitrov, it seems similar
https://github.com/DaGhostman/vscode-tree-view

Answer (score 0):

I am experimenting with the switch from Webstorm to VS Code and the file explorer was the one thing which hurt my eyes.

Luckily I found this plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chadalen.vscode-jetbrains-icon-theme

Before and after:

[image: Before]

[image: After]